# combine rows in r, summing values and concatenating characters; combining factor levels

Tags: r, sum, concatenation, aggregate

I want to combine two or more rows, such that the numeric values for variables (v1..5) are summed and the character values, which are factor levels are combined like this:

R1, 0  1 1 1  1 ,  d  e  f
R2, 1  3 0 1  2 ,  l  k  s

combining R1 and R2

R1R2, 2 4  1  2  3  dl ek fs

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: d, e ,f and l, k, s are unique factor levels, so I want to say 'combine factor levels f and s into a new factor level fs' which will concatenate the other (character) factor levels and sum the integer values into a new single row whilst simultaneously deleting the two previous rows that it combined. Would this possibly be a pipe function where you pipe two rows into one new one?

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group = gl(n()/2, 2)) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("v")), sum) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("f")), toString) %>%
 summarise_all(first) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-group)

     v1    v2    v3    v4    v5 fa    fb    fc   
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     2     4     1     2     3 d, l  e, k  f, s
```

Here it assigns every two rows into the same group, sums the variables starting with `v` and concatenates the variables starting with `f`.

Or the same based on variable class:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group = gl(n()/2, 2)) %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, sum) %>%
 mutate_if(is.character, toString) %>%
 summarise_all(first) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R `lapply` we can check for class of the columns and take action accordingly

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) 
                 if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else paste0(x, collapse = "")))

#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 fa fb fc
#1  2  4  1  2  3 dl ek fs
```

---

If we want to do this for every `n` rows we can use `aggregate`

```
n <- 2
aggregate(.~rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each  = n, length.out = nrow(df)), df, 
            function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else paste0(x, collapse = ""))[-1]
```

Comment: This will do it for all the rows though. I think they want to do it for every n rows...